# remove and uninstall OpenSSL

Tags: centos, openssl

I have installed minimal `CentOS` 6.5 on a VM. The OpenSSL version `1.0.1e-fips`.

Now I want to install a software that it highly recommended to install OpenSSL 1.0.1c, I should install it via get from `openssl.org`. I believe that means I should install 1.0.1c verion of openssl, and I should remove the 1.0.1e.

I tried `yum remove openssl` but gives me

```
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Now my question is how remove default openssl? First install the one recommended and then remove the default one?
How can i do that?

Comment: OpenSSL is a fairly basic component that many other things depend on, and if you do manage to remove it your system may well be unusable. All `1.0.1*` versions are API-compatible so there is no logical reason any software should need a _lower_ patch level; ask them, and you may well learn this 'recommendation' is years old and obsolete.

Comment: Ok, Thx sir, i will continue with this version, hope not getting problem.
thx sir

Comment: default openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 on my SL/Centos 7.2.It was not possible to downgrade.When used centos 6.5.Its possible to downgrade openssl to centos 6.x.

Comment: @AlirezaAzadi - In addition to Dave Thomson's advice, ***never*** remove the system version of OpenSSL. You will likely break the package manager, and its difficult to recover from that. Do ***not*** even perform a manual update. If you want to update or upgrade OpenSSL, then install a new copy in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do that. Downgrading OpenSSL version can (re)introduce security bugs (and also break other packages installed on your system)

If you really need (not sure why, as all the revisions of the same version should be compatible) to do that, I would install an other version of the library in some private path (`/opt/openssl`?) and then set LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to force the executable to load that version instead of the system one.

Edit: I'm suggesting to install the other version of the library in `/opt/openssl` instead of `/usr/local/lib` because in some distributions, that path is used by default. That would mean that an older version of the `openssl` would be used by default for **all** the applications on the system. And I still don't think that downgrading `openssl` is a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

When you did:

```
# yum update
```

You got dependencies problem.You should solve it first.

I think you can do downgrade if repos still provide openssl older version:

```
# yum downgrade openssl
```

When you used :

```
# yum remove openssl
```

Some packages will remove it too. When some packages depended on openssl package.

Comment: Ok, so i did not use yum update till i solve it.
When i try yum downgrade openssl it says : 
Only Upgrade available on package: openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6.x86_64
Nothing to do.

And when try to remove the error in main question happens.

Comment: When you want to install it manually. You can download it from rpm.pbone.net or you want to compile openssl old version from openssl.org

Comment: @Moderators of Stack Exchage should be aware when some users provided wrong information.They posted their question.They didnt provide a good information about their problem.

Comment: @moderator, I used android UC broswer to post it. I typed # but it did not show up.That I didnt want to enter new line. Because the hash # disappeared.Sometime I posted answers and comments. I got a error message.Maybe that caused # disappear.

Comment: @moderator,I can not enter new lines when I used Android UC browser.When I entered it and posted it directly.